# Update using single row query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have around thousands of records and I need to update one column that will have the phone number. I have the phone number like this in my table (customers)-

> 12345678,888-888-8888,(888)-333-5555,555-555

However I need to update the column with a single query so that all the thousand records should get updated and make sure data should look like this

> (888)-333-5555

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Do you want the exact same value for the phone number column in every row in your database table?

Comment: Phone number can be different but format should be same for all the rows (888)-888-8888.

Comment: You are asking how to write an UPDATE statement in SQL, correct? One that will accomplish the task you described in your post, right?

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet Singh.  If the parens, hyphens, etc. are ignored, do all the records consistently have 10 digits, or are there some with 11, or 7, or additional nation-codes, etc.  Does the data uniformly contain 10-digits?

Comment: @Abra....Yes, I want to write an Update sql statement.

Comment: @alexgibbs....Yes the records will have the 10 digits but we can't ingore parens, hyphens etc.

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet Singh.  If every record has 10 digits, what does the `555-555` record in your example data represent?  Thanks

Comment: @alexgibbs...sorry my mistake...there will only 10 digit data not less than not more than...if column have the data like this 1234567890 then I want to update in (123)-456-7890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each phone-number in the target table indeed has 10 digits, in order, with variable parens and hyphens etc., a two-stage regex replacement can reformat it.

An example is below, using a table called `LOREM` with phone number field `IPSUM`.

Create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE LOREM(IPSUM VARCHAR2(32));
INSERT INTO LOREM VALUES ('1234567890');
INSERT INTO LOREM VALUES ('888-888-8888');
INSERT INTO LOREM VALUES ('(888)-333-5555');
COMMIT;
```

Initial State:

```
SELECT IPSUM 
FROM LOREM
ORDER BY 1 ASC;

            IPSUM
_________________
(888)-333-5555
1234567890
888-888-8888
```

Then make the update.  This does two regex-replacements.  First, it throws out anything that is not a number.  Then it reformats the 10 digits into (###)-###-####:

```
UPDATE LOREM SET IPSUM = REGEXP_REPLACE(
   REGEXP_REPLACE(IPSUM, '[^0-9]{1,}', NULL, 1, 0),
    '([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})', '(\1)-\2-\3',1,0 );


3 rows updated.
```

Then check the result:

```
SELECT IPSUM
FROM LOREM
ORDER BY 1 ASC;

            IPSUM
_________________
(123)-456-7890
(888)-333-5555
(888)-888-8888


3 rows selected.
```

Comment: thank you for the solutions...if possible can you please explain what this code - '[^0-9]{1,}', NULL, 1, 0 means and second one is '(\1)-\2-\3',1,0